# Not All Paths Return a Value. Does Switch behave differently from Select?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Good day. I'm transitioning to C# from vb.net and this particular switch statement  in my calendar is working on vb.net but not on C#.

Here is my code in **VB.Net**:

```
Function getlabel(ByVal day As DayOfWeek, ByVal row As Integer) As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Select Case day
        Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return su1
                Case 2
                    Return su2
                Case 3
                    Return su3
                Case 4
                    Return su4
                Case 5
                    Return su5
                Case 6
                    Return su6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Monday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return m1
                Case 2
                    Return m2
                Case 3
                    Return m3
                Case 4
                    Return m4
                Case 5
                    Return m5
                Case 6
                    Return m6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return tu1
                Case 2
                    Return tu2
                Case 3
                    Return tu3
                Case 4
                    Return tu4
                Case 5
                    Return tu5
                Case 6
                    Return tu6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Wednesday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return w1
                Case 2
                    Return w2
                Case 3
                    Return w3
                Case 4
                    Return w4
                Case 5
                    Return w5
                Case 6
                    Return w6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Thursday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return th1
                Case 2
                    Return th2
                Case 3
                    Return th3
                Case 4
                    Return th4
                Case 5
                    Return th5
                Case 6
                    Return th6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Friday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return f1
                Case 2
                    Return f2
                Case 3
                    Return f3
                Case 4
                    Return f4
                Case 5
                    Return f5
                Case 6
                    Return f6
            End Select

        Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
            Select Case row
                Case 1
                    Return sa1
                Case 2
                    Return sa2
                Case 3
                    Return sa3
                Case 4
                    Return sa4
                Case 5
                    Return sa5
                Case 6
                    Return sa6
            End Select

    End Select
End Function
```

Here is the code I tried to recreate in **C#**:

```
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label getlabel(DayOfWeek day, int row)
    {
        switch (day)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return su1;
                    case 2:
                        return su2;
                    case 3:
                        return su3;
                    case 4:
                        return su4;
                    case 5:
                        return su5;
                    case 6:
                        return su6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return m1;
                    case 2:
                        return m2;
                    case 3:
                        return m3;
                    case 4:
                        return m4;
                    case 5:
                        return m5;
                    case 6:
                        return m6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return tu1;
                    case 2:
                        return tu2;
                    case 3:
                        return tu3;
                    case 4:
                        return tu4;
                    case 5:
                        return tu5;
                    case 6:
                        return tu6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return w1;
                    case 2:
                        return w2;
                    case 3:
                        return w3;
                    case 4:
                        return w4;
                    case 5:
                        return w5;
                    case 6:
                        return w6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return th1;
                    case 2:
                        return th2;
                    case 3:
                        return th3;
                    case 4:
                        return th4;
                    case 5:
                        return th5;
                    case 6:
                        return th6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return f1;
                    case 2:
                        return f2;
                    case 3:
                        return f3;
                    case 4:
                        return f4;
                    case 5:
                        return f5;
                    case 6:
                        return f6;
                }

                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return sa1;
                    case 2:
                        return sa2;
                    case 3:
                        return sa3;
                    case 4:
                        return sa4;
                    case 5:
                        return sa5;
                    case 6:
                        return sa6;
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

I can't tell if the behavior of Switch is different of I tranlated the "As System.Windows.Forms. Label" wrong? I hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: You should have the same `Not All Paths...` error in VB - it cant know that your Case statements are exhaustive.  The difference is that in VB it is just a warning

Comment: Speaking of exhausting - that could be collapsed by eliminating the Select case row and use an array:  `Case DayOfWeek.Monday ... Return MondayLabels(row)`

Comment: The answer is yes, they are different. Because, they are two completely  different languages. The generated assemblies are compatible but not the syntax.

Comment: You should set `Option Strict On` in VB - you'll probably get a ton of errors then in your VB code. That'll help you to properly change to C#.

Comment: @Plutonix, Thank you for the tip. My coding skills aren't really not that good. I'll collapsing it.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah. I just tried it. I'm planning to leave VB altogether and focus on C#.

Comment: @SlicedBread - I used to be a VB developer and jumped to C# about 10 years ago. There are a few things that VB is still better at, but C# is by far my preferred language now. It's much cleaner.

Comment: Conversion of VB's very powerful Select will become more of an issue with complex cases because C# only allows constants for switch cases. All of the online converters ignore this when they _should_ translate VB Select to C# as an `if...else if...else if...else` ladder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are returning a value from a switch statement, you need to care about the default case for the switch as well, since each case is a code path in the method, Or else you have to use a `return null;` outside all your `switches`.

You need to add to all your switch statements

```
 default: return null;
 break;
```

or `return null` out side all cases and before leaving the block, So it will return from the method if any matching cases were found else `null` will be returned, the code will looks like this :

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label getlabel(DayOfWeek day, int row)
{
   switch (day)
   {
     // cases here 
       switch (row)
       {
         // inner switch with its own cases
        // no specified default case
       }
     // no specified default case
   }
  return null;
}
```

In the case of VB, you will definitely get the same error if you run with `Option Strict On` in that case you have to use `case else` or simply `return null` before ending the function block

Comment: While true, it doesn't answer why the VB code did not require such constructs

Comment: clearer to just put a `return null` at the end - not in any `switch`.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes. It really bothers me. I'm really starting to regret dwelling on VB. The transition is really confusing.

Comment: @SlicedBread commenting on transition point: the reverse (from C# to VB.Net) is actually not so bad. ;)

Comment: Just checked, all code paths not returning will only cause a warning in VB unless Option Strict is on. Did you get a warning with your old code?

Comment: If you run the VB code with `Option Strict On` then same error will appears there as well. until that such errors will not shown

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was gonna say no but upon reading un-lucky's cooment. I turned Option Strict On and there it was. A warning.

Comment: @SlicedBread Should have been a warning even *without* Option Strict On, since that turns the warning into an error. Regardless, glad you are seeing it now.

Comment: Looks like I picked up some bad habits from VB. Could you guys direct me to some resources that will help my transition? I'm kinda bit ashamed of posting here if I encounter problems. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET actually it is configurable: with Option Strict On you can still set some errors as warnings, and Not All Paths is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This design fixes the error as even if none of the cases finds a match the function returns a value, here it would be nothing if no matches occur.

```
Function getlabel(ByVal day As DayOfWeek, ByVal row As Integer) As Label
  Dim result As Label = Nothing
  Select Case day
    Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
      Select Case row
      Case 1
        result = su1
      Case 2
        result = su2
      Case 3
        result = su3
      Case 4
        result = su4
      Case 5
        result = su5
      Case 6
        result = su6
    End Select
  'continue your cases.
  End Select
  Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This program in VB.NET will work:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim result = MyFunc(3)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub

    Function MyFunc(ByVal variableName As Int16) As MyEnum

        Select Case variableName
            Case 1
                Return MyEnum.ValueOne
            Case 2
                Return MyEnum.ValueTwo
            'Case Else
                'Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid value")
        End Select
    End Function

End Module

Enum MyEnum
    ValueOne
    ValueTwo
End Enum
```

`MyFunc` will return 0 as the default. In C# the same program will complain that not all paths return a value and compilation will fail.

For VB.NET it will only show a warning and compilation will pass. If you turn *Option Explicit* on, then VB.NET will also fail compilation.

So to answer your question, in C# it is not optional: You must return a value.

Please read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities/) article on C# switch statement-it is very informative and detailed.